# How to save chrono time in list in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, time, c++-chrono

I am working on c++ code where I am trying to save `chrono time` in a list so that I can read the value later on and can calculate the time duration.

The reason of saving the time in list is because I have multiple objects where I need to capture the current time of when that object was detected and then later when that object goes away, I have to calculate duration of time for that object.

```
list <double> dTimeList;

auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

auto it = dTimeList.begin();
advance(it, detection.object_id);

dTimeList.insert(it, start ); //But this is giving error
```

> Error (active)    E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::list<_Ty, _Alloc>::insert [with _Ty=double, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list
>
> Error C2664   'std::_List_iterator>> std::list<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>::insert(std::_List_const_iterator>>,unsigned __int64,const _Ty &)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point' to '_Ty &&'

Comment: What's the type of `dTimeList`?

Comment: @Holt Apologies, I have updated the type.

Comment: You need to store the correct type in your list, i.e., `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point`, and not `double`. `std::chrono::time_point` are not implicitly convertible to numerical types, for good reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `list<double>` is wrong here. You need to store a list of type `list<decltype(start)>`, which is the same as `list<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>>`. The following code should work:

```
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
list <decltype(start)> dTimeList;

auto it = dTimeList.begin();
advance(it, detection.object_id);
dTimeList.insert(it, start );
```

Note that I've changed the order or the list declaration and `start`. You can also use some `typedef`/`using` declarator of course.

And finally, for completeness, `high_resolution_clock` has an own alias for the above type, [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)    .

Answer (score 4):

`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`  returns an instance of

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point
```

...which is, for good reasons, not convertible to `double`. If you want to store time points, you need to have an adequate list:

```
std::list<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point> dTimeList;
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments: "You need to store the correct type in your list, i.e., std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point, and not double. std::chrono::time_point are not implicitly convertible to numerical types, for good reasons."

I have provided a small working example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>> dTimeList;

    dTimeList.push_back(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));
    dTimeList.push_back(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());

    std::chrono::duration<double> difference = dTimeList[0]-dTimeList[1];
    std::cout << "Time difference is: " << difference.count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```